# How to show nearest store based on zipcode

Tags: xcode, zipcode

I am creating an app tha is for a a bussines that has several stores around the state.
How can i show the information for the nearest sores based in the zip code?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is:

1. Convert the ZIP code to geographical coordinates (longitude and latitude).
2. Compute the distance of each store to this coordinate.
3. Order the results by distance, ascending.

Step 2 can be optimized a bit -- for example, you might limit the search to those stores in the same state.  You may also want to limit the number of stores returned if you are only going to display 10, for example.

This is about all the detail I can provide since your question is quite general.

Comment: Sorry i meant in xcode, and the distance will b withing 15 miles

Comment: Your question is too general to answer with specific code examples.  You have not provided any information about how store data is stored or whether you even have access to their coordinates, for example.  Additionally, this site isn't a "write my application for me" site.  I've given you a general attack plan; it's up to you to execute it.